# find matched file_ids within the dat files in the directory and copy them to a different directory

Tags: bash, unix

I have a `file_id = 840920` and I have to pick only the child files that belong to the `file_id = 840920`. The names of the dat file are different but within all the dat file, the parent file id is available. Example of a record is shown as:

```
445973129|2602325065|840920|1|RUPATXEM14|LVP|||20180924 18:25:10
445973130|2602325066|840920|2|RP_STG_TEST_WED|LVP|||20180924 18:23
```

So I want to map my search only for the third column and extract those dat files and copy them to a different folder.

Below is my code in unix to do the same. Need some help for more suggestions or better ways to handle the same.
My query is I am able to print `matched_file_id` values when I run the while loop separately but the code is not printing showing the `matched_file_id` values when I included them as part of my code:
Any suggestions please?

```
cat $TMP/TempBatchData.txt | while read FILE_ID #FILE_ID = 840920
do
for file in *CDI*.dat; do
echo $file >> all_CDI_LIST.txt
done
while IFS= read -r line; do
matched_file_id=`cat $line | cut -f3 -d"|" | sort -u` # echo all the third 
column values
done < "all_CDI_LIST.txt" 

if [[ $matched_file_id == $FILE_ID ]]; then 
echo $line >> final_cdi_list.txt
fi
done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Issues, suspicious fragments:

- `$matched_file_id` contains zero or more values, comparison to `$FILE_ID` only succeeds when there is one value;
- `$matched_file_id` is set once per `line`, comparison to `$FILE_ID` is performed once per `FILE_ID`;
- there is an extra `done` at the end(?);
- `column values` should belong to a comment;
- variables are not quoted;
- `TMP` should be set.

This is a rewritten procedure. It's not completely equivalent but the approach seems better:

```
TMP="/the/right/path"
find . -type f -name '*CDI*.dat' \
       -exec sh -c '
          <"$1" cut -f3 -d"|" | grep -qFx -f "$TMP/TempBatchData.txt"
       ' sh {} \; -print > final_cdi_list.txt
```

Explanation:

1. `find` finds all files matching the `*CDI*.dat` pattern.
2. For every such file a shell is run to process a pipe.
3. `cut` extracts the third column.
4. `grep` quietly (`-q`) checks if any literal string (`-F`) from the given file (`-f`) exists in the output of `cut` as a whole line (`-x`).
5. If so, `find` will print the path to the file.

Notes, differences, quirks:

- `find` acts recursively. To process only the current directory without subdirectories you need `-maxdepth 1` (not required by POSIX) or a POSIX solution from [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/275637/108618), or let the shell expand `*CDI*.dat` (`find *CDI*.dat -type f -exec …`) which has its downsides.
- `find` will print paths with leading `./`. To obtain base names you need `-printf '%f\n'` (non-POSIX) instead of `-print` or e.g. `-exec basename {} \;` (POSIX compliant) instead of `-print`.
- `grep -F` matches literal strings. In your code each line from `$TMP/TempBatchData.txt` undergoes implicit processing twice:

  1. with `read FILE_ID` (as opposed to `read -r FILE_ID`),
  2. inside the `[[ $matched_file_id == $FILE_ID ]]` (comparisons using `[[` perform pattern matching against the unquoted string on the right hand side, not just a plain string comparison).

  I'm not sure if you rely on this. You may want to adjust my code.
- The title mentions copying files to another directory. With my approach you don't need to process `final_cdi_list.txt` to do so. Just use `-exec cp {} "/another/directory" \;` instead of `-print`.

The whole job of finding files that match can be done with sole `grep`, you need to adjust the pattern though. Example:

```
grep -l '^[0-9]*|[0-9]*|840920|' *CDI*.dat
```

You can have many patterns in a file (`-f "$TMP/TempBatchData.txt"`) but they need to be like the above. If there are too many files matching `*CDI*.dat` you will get "argument list too long" (the approach with `for file in *CDI*.dat;` you originally used is immune to this).

Maybe adjust your directory structure (e.g. only `*CDI*.dat` files in the current directory and subdirectories, recursive search allowed or no subdirectories at all) and the pattern file format. The idea is to use

```
grep -lr -f "$TMP/TempBatchData.txt"
```

or something similar. Note `-r` is not required by POSIX, in this example its meaning is from GNU `grep`: read all files under the current working directory, recursively.

A single `grep` process should be faster than any solution that uses `find -exec` or `read` (and matches strings in whatever way).